# Why does the nested loop start decrease by 2 originally?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with this code. It may be simple, but I'm still a beginner and with Java. The nested for loop, when I print it out looks like this: 10,8,6,4,2 and I was just wondering why it's going down by 2 rather than 3?
Here is my code

```
int z = 0;

for(int x = 0; x < 10; x = x+2){
    for(int j = 10; j >= 1; j = j-3){

       System.out.println(j);
        z++;
        j++;   
    }

    z++;
}
```

EDIT: sorry, I used System.out.println(j); but I printed j before I increment j in the loop

Comment: `j = j-3` and `j++`? `j++` means `j = j + 1;`

Comment: I don't see anything here that would print anything. Is this all the code?

Comment: I'm looking for a Syso method. Please post the complete code.

Comment: it's just in my main method!

Answer (score 1):

Before each single iteration of the inner loop ends, it increments **j** by **1**.

```
j++; // +1
```

When it actually ends, it decrements by **3**. which gives you total decrement of **2**.

```
for(...; ...; j = j-3) // -2
```

Comment: I meant when I print j before the incrementation!

Comment: @Razar yes exactly. Notice the lifecycle that goes on & on in here.

Comment: @Razar as Sparta points out, the `j = j - 3` isn't applied until the end of the block of code associated with the for loop

Comment: Oh! that makes sense, does this happen with all four loops? I've never really noticed it before!

Comment: @Razar `for` loops, yes.

Comment: Right, sorry for the typo! And thank you for taking the time to explain that

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are adding `1` to `j`(`j++`) after `j = j - 3`.
This is counter-intuitive and you are technically applying this to `j`: `j = j - 2`.

Rather, do this:

```
int z = 0;
for(int x =0; x<10; x = x +2){
    for( int j = 10; j>=1; j = j-3)
        z++;
    z++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int z = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x = x+2){
        for(int j = 10; j >= 1; j = j-3){

           System.out.println(j);
            z++;
            j++;   //it's because of this, try to remove this and it will go down by 3
           System.out.println(j); //if you will add this line, it will show j incremented by 1, for example 10 by 11 in the first iteration then 11 - 3 = 8 hence creates confusion from your side.
        }

        z++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. The inner loop start with j = 10.

Before the end of first iteration, j increases by 1 ( j++ ). **j = 11**.
After the first iteration ends, j decreases by 3 ( j-3 ). **j = 8**. 
So, **j = 8** will be carried to the second iteration, which means for every next iteration, j decreases by **2**.